# Linux root directory owned by 911:911

Tags: ubuntu, root, root-filesystem

I run a Ubuntu 20.04 home server and, while doing something else entirely, happened to notice that my root "/" directory is apparently owned by the user:group 911:911. Checked passwd and there aren't any users or groups with that name/UID/GID. All other subdirectories are owned by root:root as expected. I haven't actually encountered any problems with the server thus far, so I'm not sure if this will even be problematic. I have no idea when this would have happened, or how... I have three questions about this:

1. Are there any anticipated problems to normal operation I should expect from this?
2. Since I've not noticed any problems, would changing the owner to root:root as would be expected be likely to cause any problems, and should I do so?
3. Does anything spring to mind for anyone as far as what UID:GID 911 would be, is that UID/GID typically reserved for anything by the system?

Edit: `grep -rw 911 /etc/` doesn't return anything.

Output of `grep -E '^(group|passwd)' /etc/nsswitch.conf`:

```
passwd:    files systemd
group:     files systemd
```

Output of `find / '(' -user 911 -o -group 911 ')' -ls`:

```
        2      4 drwxr-xr-x  24 911      911          4096 Apr 17 03:18 /
 15733493      4 drwxrwxr-x   2 911      911          4096 Nov  5 14:08 /var/lib/docker/overlay2/2cf57691692f2dda6b2d60313d28ef601f226a8c9d731a111526f21e4fbfe4bf/diff/defaults
 15733488      4 drwxrwxr-x   2 911      911          4096 Oct 30 14:02 /var/lib/docker/overlay2/2cf57691692f2dda6b2d60313d28ef601f226a8c9d731a111526f21e4fbfe4bf/diff/app
 15859939      4 drwxrwxr-x   2 911      911          4096 Nov  5 14:08 /var/lib/docker/overlay2/fe59f9c3424fce86dfb204bc273342510be6724c1274fd46c8eda2c75d4122a7/diff/defaults
 15859934      4 drwxrwxr-x   2 911      911          4096 Oct 30 14:02 /var/lib/docker/overlay2/fe59f9c3424fce86dfb204bc273342510be6724c1274fd46c8eda2c75d4122a7/diff/app
 15733146      0 -rwxrwxr-x   1 911      man             0 Oct 30 14:02 /var/lib/docker/overlay2/3f79bdf7138fad17aaf936f2525c9242fa3b96998e1475fbdf353c96b3bab290/diff/var/mail/abc
 15860199      4 drwxrwxr-x   2 911      911          4096 Nov  5 14:08 /var/lib/docker/overlay2/e107d6245eaab055d35220de32d10c6a9af3dc3af17dbab36735472d5b77d9de/diff/defaults
 15860193      4 drwxrwxr-x   2 911      911          4096 Oct 30 14:02 /var/lib/docker/overlay2/e107d6245eaab055d35220de32d10c6a9af3dc3af17dbab36735472d5b77d9de/diff/app
 15598770      4 drwxrwxr-x   3 911      911          4096 Apr 15 01:22 /var/lib/docker/volumes/c0bcd0a92d70b7b9f970f07f6371bdffe110e367e7bbf51a8072f38118c7533b/_data
 15598772      4 drwxrwxr-x   2 911      911          4096 Apr 15 01:22 /var/lib/docker/volumes/4f8ab59ac78fcbb8b7f6c36cf4e664f03446071fa455f8d8be2a014dbf5bb9e4/_data
 15598764      4 drwxrwxr-x   2 911      911          4096 Apr 15 01:21 /var/lib/docker/volumes/35c7f99c05d42f281553ecf72eb101b3ff2e1ee658154183381e5d48ac442443/_data
 15598753      4 drwxrwxr-x   3 911      911          4096 Apr 15 01:20 /var/lib/docker/volumes/43e8203bfb752d770ccee74946a747a44caf136307bdb6c004414a592c504eee/_data
 15598762      4 drwxrwxr-x   3 911      911          4096 Apr 15 01:21 /var/lib/docker/volumes/af2fafa4ef632956c2d82f84b51c78021b974cad0f35e2e06a5a49774a462bc0/_data
 15598756      4 drwxrwxr-x   3 911      911          4096 Apr 15 01:20 /var/lib/docker/volumes/1d36770cd560d95970c3cc7b0f59a2e7523375710921df8e72b6b072763d29bf/_data
```

You're right, I somehow impressively managed to screw up copy-pasting it the first time... there's a number of docker directories, so yeah, probably something related to what you linked in your first comment, though no idea how docker would have ended up changing ownership of `/`

Comment: How was the system originally setup? See also https://www.reddit.com/r/docker/comments/mgslyf/linuxserverio_images_user_911/

Comment: 911 is a phone number for emergency services in some parts of the world, it also suggests the Sep 11 attack on the US, so could be remnant of past or current malicious activity.

Comment: Does `find / '(' -user 911 -o -group 911 ')' -ls` reveal other files with those ids? What about `ps -u 911`?

Comment: Does `grep -rw 911 /etc/` return anything?

Comment: What are the permissions of `/`? What's the output of `stat /`

Comment: Also, what's the output of `grep -E '^(group|passwd)' /etc/nsswitch.conf`?

Comment: `grep -rw 911 /etc/` doesn't return anything. `find / '(' -user 911 -o -group 911 ')' -ls` doesn't work, says it's an invalid expression with binary operator -o with nothing before it. 
Output of `stat /`:
File: /
  Size: 4096            Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   directory
Device: 822h/2082d      Inode: 2           Links: 24
Access: (0755/drwxr-xr-x)  Uid: (  911/ UNKNOWN)   Gid: (  911/ UNKNOWN)
Access: 2023-04-17 03:18:27.269421812 -0400
Modify: 2023-04-17 03:18:26.509424346 -0400
Change: 2023-04-17 03:18:26.509424346 -0400
 Birth: -

Comment: Output of `grep -E '^(group|passwd)' /etc/nsswitch.conf`:

passwd:         files systemd
group:          files systemd

Comment: Please edit your question to add the information in. `find` error suggests you haven't entered the command as shown.